# How can we keep connection alive to pool on own PHP client with own server

Tags: php, multithreading, connection-pooling

**How can we keep connections alive (put it to pool) on PHP client with own another server (such as: CORBA     Server, Thrift Server,...)?**

Can i do it? PHP is a script language only, a PHP Server give a thread for each request and end this thread after processing completely. That means, anything will be lost after that so that i can't store any thing long term (this case, i need store a Connection Pool to keep connections).

We knew, if **our client is a Java, C#, C/C++**,... we can make an own Connection Pool (or other name) to reuse connectons long term for multi-threads. Otherwise, if **server that own client connect is MySql, SQL Server, MongoDB**... we can set "persistence" (or orther way), because those servers support connection pool for their client. Unluckly, in my case, **my client is PHP and my server is Java with using Thrift** to connect them.

Could you give me advice? Thank for yours help!

Comment: You don't have a PHP server. You have a **web server** and you're using PHP to process requests. Of course, that's request-reply and naturally you can't create a socket pool because the script is done for once it serves something. You need to run a PHP script that never ends (daemon or whatever you prefer) in order to implement that. But since you stuck so many unnecessary details in your question, it's difficult to see what exactly you're optimizing and whether your approach is even ok.

Comment: Thank, of course i have known how PHP technology work, but, i call briefly "PHP Server" that means web server that use PHP script (Apache, Nginx,..).
My problem exactly is **"how can we use multi-thread with PHP?"**. In your recommendation, could you tell me how to run a daemon PHP script on webserver (Apache is in my case).

Comment: You can't start a daemon and then have it talk to Apache. You can start a daemon and connect to that daemon directly. You could have Apache invoke a PHP script, script connects to the daemon (written in PHP or other language of your preference) and the daemon uses the pool of connections it had towards the service you're interested into. As for multithreading, that's a completely different matter but you can check php.net/pthreads for that.

Comment: That mean, i create a C++ daemon (for example) and run it, my PHP Server connect to it, and it connect to Java Server (or other):
|| [**PHP Server (Apache)** ---local--- **C++ Server**] ---global--- **Java Server** ||

Comment: Yes, you just need to implement a protocol between PHP script and your C++ daemon so they can understand each other.